Why is the subgroup of the adelic image $E_{/\mathbb{Q}}$ open?
I am reading Serre's 1972  paper (English) Proposition 22 (24 in English version) where he proves that no elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ can have surjective adelic image.
In the proof he says

This shows that $\varphi_{\infty}(G)$ is contained in the subgroup $H_{\Delta}$ of $\operatorname{Aut}[tors]$ consisting of elements $a$ such that $$\varepsilon(a_2)=\left(\frac{\Delta}{\operatorname{det}a_m}\right).$$ It is clear that $H_{\Delta}$ is an open subgroup of index $2$ in $\operatorname{Aut}E[tors]$.


I do not follow why $H_{\Delta}$ must be an open subgroup of index $2$ in $\operatorname{Aut}E[tors]$?

Is it index 2 because the signature would partition the group into two? Open because it is discrete? I could be miserably wrong.

Also, I am not sure why we are in particular only considering the $2$ torsion elements?

I don't think I entirely understand how the proof proves what it claims.

I am reading the French version and not the English one, which says the subgroup where $\epsilon(a_2) = \alpha_\Delta(\text{det} a_m)$.
This is a subgroup because it is the kernel of the map to $\pm 1$ given by
$$
a \mapsto \epsilon^{-1}(a_2) \alpha_\Delta(\text{det} (a_m)).
$$
(the inverse isn't really necessary since the target has size $2$). This subgroup is either all of $\text{Aut}(E[\text{tors}])$ or it's an index 2 subgroup, again because the target has size 2. But the map to $\pm 1$ is obviously surjective since you can just pick a different $a_m$ if the sign of your determinant was wrong, so it must be an index two subgroup.
The open-ness follows from the continuity (it's the composition of a bunch of continuous maps and it has a discrete target). This is exactly what you said, so you are not "miserably wrong" as you worried!
You asked why we chose $2$-torsion and $m$-torsion to focus on; the point is that there is some subtle relation between the Galois-action on $2$-torsion and other points coming from class field theory -- the Galois character relates to the sign of the permutation of the action on the $2$-torsion points, but also to the action on the $m$-torsion points for some auxiliary $m$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$.

Firstly, thank you so so much for this lovely answer! I've sat with this for a while and I would just like to confirm if I got this correctly - essentially, we have a commutative diagram with the maps $G \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut} E[tors] \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut} E[2] \rightarrow {\pm1}$ and $G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}^{\times} \rightarrow {\pm 1 }$ and then as the first sequence is surjective and both sequences are same up to sign, it must be the case $\varphi_{\infty}(G)$ is index $2$ for reasons you described above? (ctd.)

Secondly, I was wondering if you could possible give me a reference so I could read more about the Galois character relating $2$-torsion and $m$-torsion points? I've read some class field theory before so hopefully I should be able to read further?

Yes, that is right (to comment one). And I don't have a better relation than this proof. I shouldn't've said "coming from class field theory," which is true but pretentious, we're just using the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$ is contained in some cyclotomic field.

Thank you so much! One last follow up question before I (hopefully) bugger off and stop bothering ya - I uh still don't see how that statement helps? As $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$ (which is the extension that contains 2-torsion) is contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$...? I know that $\mathbb{Q}(E[n])$ is Galois for every $n$ and is contained in a cyclotomic extension, but I don't know if that means the union $\mathbb{Q}(E[tors])$ would be contained in an cyclotomic extension... I don't even know if that is relevant? I'm really sorry I just don't understand what role the $m$ is playing here?

In general, it is not the case that $\mathbb{Q}(E[n])$ is contained in a cyclotomic extension, because it isn't abelian over $\mathbb{Q}$.
The $m$ is auxiliary. The point is that it turns the statement from a statement about a character of $G$ being related to the sign of $\alpha_2$ into a statement about another one of the $\alpha_i$ being related to $\alpha_2$, and this is what lets us know that $G$ lands in a proper subgroup and not all of $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_f)$.

Aaah! I see. That makes sense! Thank you so very much for your answer and your patience!! :)
